# Can some data be separated in a Tcp connection?

Tags: c#, networking, tcp

my question is simple. Can some data be separated in a tcp connection (as title says)?  For example if I  call `MySocket.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("this is a test!");`, may I get 2 separate receive operations like "this is" and " a test" from the other side of connection?  Namely how much *reliable* is the Tcp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP is usually used as a **stream**; no guarantee **whatsoever** is made that the "send" and "receive" operations will match up one-to-one. It would be technically valid (but unlikley) to  have to read 15 times, getting 1 byte each time. As such, there are usually two modes of operation:

- read until the end of the stream (the sender closes their outbound socket after sending the message)
- add some kind of framing protocol

  - for text-based protocols this is often a sentinel value, such as a `0` or an end-of-line (whether that is CR, LF, CRLF or LFCR is up to you!)
  - for binary protocols, this is often a length-prefix in some well-defined format, telling you how many bytes to consider for the next message

(but the line is blurry; the redis protocol, for example, is roughly text-based, but uses a plain-text length-prefix of the form `${n}\r\n{data}\r\n`, where `{n}` is the number of bytes expressed as an ASCII string, and `{data}` is the raw `n` bytes)

Comment: Namely we should implement our own packet fragmentation :) Thanks a lot! _Edit:_ Cool advice which is I'm thinking about.

Comment: @PilawyerDev do you mean fragmentation? or do you mean framing? since you're already only calling `Send` once, there isn't much more you can do in terms of fragmentation. If you mean *framing*, then - if you are sending multiple separate messages: yes, absolutely, without question

Comment: Oh, framing yes! Sorry.

Comment: @PilawyerDev I've blogged about this in the past, btw: http://blog.marcgravell.com/2013/02/how-many-ways-can-you-mess-up-io.html

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel, consider using existing solutions like the XDR protocol, or protocol buffers, or even WCF.

Comment: How I missed that post? I'm one of your follower!

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it should be noted that protocol buffers expressly lacks a framing protocol; if you just use vanilla protobuf, it will attempt to read to the EOF; unless you mean protorpc?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I love reinventing! I've already built a R-UDP and I'm happy now because my solution needs some specific protocol like this one. Also thanks btw. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they can be sent as multiple parts. You can't assume single send operation will result in single receive in other end.

Read [stephen cleary's article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html) on "Message Framing" for more info. Also [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37496/TCP-IP-Protocol-Design-Message-Framing). and a sample [message framing code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/sample-code-length-prefix-message.html)